# Como fazer validação de url da rota dinâmica usando useEffect no Next

Tags: react, typescript, next.js

Criei uma rota dinâmica mas preciso que aceite somente número, pois se trata de um id único do cliente. Exemplo: [www.cadastro.com.br/cliente/123456](http://www.cadastro.com.br/cliente/123456)

Se for digitado um valor diferente de número na url, a página dá erro no carregamento.

```
import { CustomLayout } from '../../components/CustomLayout'
import ProjectCreate from '../../containers/ProjectCreate'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query

  useEffect(() => {
    // se id for number, carregar página
    // se for diferente de number, exibir erro de página
  }, [])

  return (
    <CustomLayout hasSider>
      {id}
      <ProjectCreate />
    </CustomLayout>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Consegui uma solução:

```
import { CustomLayout } from '../../components/CustomLayout'
import ProjectCreate from '../../containers/ProjectCreate'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id && `${id}`.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
      router.push('/clientes')
    }
  }, [router, id])

  return (
    <CustomLayout hasSider>
      {id}
      <ProjectCreate />
    </CustomLayout>
  )
}
```